# Cannot get will paginate total_entries to work, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

The problem is I would like to limit the number of results to say 30, so I put in

controller

```
@users = User.user_search(params[:name], params[:gender]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20, total_entries: 30)
  render 'user_results'
```

Say I only get 1 or 2 results back, I will still get pagination for two pages. ie will paginate seems to get the result of how many times the `total_entries` will divide in to the `per_page` value. So if I set `per_page: 20, total_entries: 110` it will give me six links adding the extra 10 as a page also.

My `User.user_search` method in the User model is

```
def self.user_search(a, b)
  users = User.all
  users = User.where('LOWER (name) LIKE LOWER(?)', "%#{a}%") if a.present?
  users = users.where('LOWER (gender) LIKE LOWER(?)', "%#{b}%") if b.present?
  return users
end
```

I have seen people with problems about using join models and will paginate but I am just using simple single model paginate. Searched lots about this. From my knowledge will paginate is passing on total_pages method to view and rendering this results. Is there a way to set a limit to my results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `total_entries` option just is a shortcut to avoid will_paginate querying the count for the results. So if you really want to limit the number of results shown in will paginate, but not mess up with the pagination results when there are only a few results you can do something like this:

```
total_records = User.user_search(params[:name], params[:gender]).count
total_entries = total_records > 30 ? 30 : total_records
@users = User.user_search(params[:name], params[:gender]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20, total_entries: total_entries)
render 'user_results'
```

You might think that this adds an additional query, but will_paginate was still going to do the `count` query in order to do its logic, here we're just overriding the total_entries by setting a max number of records to show.

Note however that by doing this you'll still get more records in the last page (if the result of dividing the total_records between the pages is not exact), or it might even be possible to ask for a higher page number and still get the 'hidden' results.

If you really need to avoid showing results over a certain number, you'll be forced to use a subquery like this:

```
@users = User.where(id: User.user_search(params[:name], params[:gender]).limit(30).map(&:id)).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
```

However, this might cause issues if instead of 30 you use a very large number.

---

Previously I was suggesting using `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods.limit`, on the search result, but will_paginate overwrites this logic when paginating.

Comment: You're right. The paginate method overwrites the limit. I'll fix my answer

Comment: Very good my friend. Was willl paginate still going to do another sql query for `total_pages`? I couldn't see it in the server output.

Comment: It does a count query for the total_entries, and with your page size it calculates the total_pages